# Sqlalchemy many to many relationship

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two tables in many to many relationship:

```
class Association(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    club_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clubs.id'), primary_key=True)
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id'), primary_key=True)
    joined_date = db.Column(db.String)
    assoc_student = db.relationship("Student")

class Club(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clubs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    location = db.Column(db.String)
    club_assoc = db.relationship("Association")

class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    age = db.Column(db.String)
    gender = db.Column(db.String)
```

Questions:

1) What is the difference between these two queries?

```
students = db.session.query(Association).filter_by(club_id='1')
students = Association.query.filter_by(club_id='1')
```

They seem to give the same result!

2) I'm trying to get a list of students with certain age but this following query doesn't work:

```
db.session.query(Association).filter_by(Association.club_id=='1', Association.assoc_student.age=='15')
```

But I get this error:

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Association.assoc_student has an attribute 'age'

That's why I'm using this one:

```
db.session.query(Student).join(Association).filter(Association.club_id=='1', Student.age=='15')
```

Is there a better way to do this without "join"? Maybe with using "backref"!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What is the difference between these two queries?

They do almost the same thing. Former is the way to query objects provided with `SQLAlchemy` (library `Flask` uses to access database).

Latter is the convenient way to query models added by `Flask-SQLAlchemy` library. It makes your queries more readable + extends query with few useful methods. Take a look at source of the `flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery` class to see them: `get_or_404()`, `first_or_404()` and `paginate()`.

Usually you want to use latter method to query objects.

> 2) I'm trying to get a list of students with certain age but this following query doesn't work.

There are two things here:

1. Be aware about the difference between [`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) and [`filter_by()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) methods. In your example you try to use `filter_by()` with SQL expressions instead of `kwargs`, which is incorrect.
2. When you're using `filter()` you can't specify columns over a relationships (like `Association.assoc_student.age`). The only allowed format is `ModelName.column_name`. That's why it fails.

> Is there a better way?

Your second approach is absolutely correct and fine to use. I don't think there is a better way to do it. Alternatively you can use code below to avoid importing `db` (if you define query in another file):

```
Student.query.join(Association).filter(Association.club_id == '1', Student.age == '15')
```

Comment: Thank you @yaroslav Admin. I am not sure about the structure of my classes, I stayed away from "backref" because I am not sure if I need it to get access to the student's culmns.

Comment: Your structure of classes is fine. If you need a `backref`, you can add it at any moment.